# Creating a Boxplot with Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, boxplot

I am using python 3 and jupyter notebook.  I have a pandas dataframe that is structured like this:

```
          location  price
Apr 25   ASHEVILLE   15.0
Apr 25   ASHEVILLE   45.0
Apr 25   ASHEVILLE   50.0
Apr 25   ASHEVILLE  120.0
Apr 25   ASHEVILLE  300.0
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

I am simply trying to create a boxplot for each location to show the range of prices among items in each location.

When I ran the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline


plt.boxplot(postings)
plt.show()
```

It returned TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

Comment: are you sure `postings` is a dataframe? try just passing the values of the column and not the whole dataframe.

Comment: It is a df.  When I try to pass plt.boxplot(postings.location) instead, it outputs IndexError: 0

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I guess you require boxplot for each location in same graph. 
I modified given dataframe to add sample data for another location which looks like-

```
   date   location month  price
0    25  ASHEVILLE   Apr   15.0
1    25  ASHEVILLE   Apr   45.0
2    25  ASHEVILLE   Apr   50.0
3    25  ASHEVILLE   Apr  120.0
4    25  ASHEVILLE   Apr  300.0
5    25  NASHVILLE   Apr   34.0
6    25  NASHVILLE   Apr   55.0
7    25  NASHVILLE   Apr   70.0
8    25  NASHVILLE   Apr  105.0
9    25  NASHVILLE   Apr   85.0
```

Now, just call boxplot on this frame and provide parameters- `column` and `by`

```
postings.boxplot(column='price', by='location')
```

￼
[image]
￼

Answer (score 3):

I guess "price" is the column of data that you want to have boxplotted. So you need to first select this column and supply only that column to `plt.boxplot`.

```
u = u"""index,location,price
    Apr 25,ASHEVILLE,15.0
    Apr 25,ASHEVILLE,45.0
    Apr 25,ASHEVILLE,50.0
    Apr 25,ASHEVILLE,120.0
    Apr 25,ASHEVILLE,300.0"""

import io
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = io.StringIO(u)

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=",", index_col=0)

plt.boxplot(df["price"])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Juding from the data, you want to have a boxplot with a single box from the 5 price values you have. You need to pass the actual data you want to make the boxplot from.

```
plt.boxplot(postings["price"])
```

Check out the examples [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/boxplot_demo.html).